# Is there a function to put expression in polynomial form

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation

Consider this polynomial in `x` and `y`:

```
poly = g x^3 + h x^3 + i x^3 + d x y + e x y + f x y + a x^2 y + b x^2 y + c x^2 y + l x y^2 + m x y^2 + j y^3 + k y^3
```

`Collect` does a bad job putting `poly` in polynomial form:

```
Collect[poly, {x, y}]
```

> $ (g+h+i)x^3 + (a+b+c)x^2 y +(j+k)y^3  +x \left((d+e+f)y + (l+m) y^2\right)$

As you can see, the last term should more properly be written as $(d+e+f)x y + (l+m)x y^2$.

I can achieve what I need by using

```
FromCoefficientRules[CoefficientRules[poly, {x,y}],{x,y}]
```

> $x^2 y (a+b+c)+x y (d+e+f)+x^3 (g+h+i)+y^3 (j+k)+x y^2 (l+m)$

Is there a built-in *Mathematica* function which achieves the same effect as `FromCoefficientRules[CoefficientRules[...]]` but requires less typing?

Comment: `Collect[poly, {x, x y, y}]` ?

Comment: @corey979 that requires knowing/typing out all possible monomial combinations that appears in `poly`.  I'm looking to avoid that.

Comment: You could make a function that will create such combinations from a given list of variables and feed it to `Collect`, e.g. `f[list_List] := Join[list, Times @@@ Subsets[list, {2}]]`. Instead writting `{x,y,z}` you'll just write `f[{x,y,z}]`.

Comment: @corey979 Your suggestion is "make a function that automates this using a combination of built-in functions".  But I already did exactly that with `FromCoefficientRules[CoefficientRules[...]]` .  My question is, is there a single built-in function that does the job?

Comment: `Plus@@MonomialList[poly,{x,y}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might satisfy your requirements:

```
Plus @@ MonomialList[poly, {x, y}]
(* (g + h + i) x^3 + (d + e + f) x y + (a + b + c) x^2 y + (l + 
    m) x y^2 + (j + k) y^3 *)
```